# What determines a final outcome of an imported character?

Tags: mass-effect-2, mass-effect

Several actions in ME1 will have consequenses in ME2. If I do multiple playthroughs (as I plan to reach 60) and handle situations completely differently, what will be the final outcome?

**Example - [UNC: Hostage](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/UNC:_Hostage)**

First game - hostage dies
Second game - hostage lives

What will be the result of an imported character in ME2? Will it always be the latest outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new playthrough of ME1 is like a new gameplus. You keep your equipment and some other things, but Shepard's decision slate is wiped clean. There is no storyline relic from the previous play in the new one. Therefore, if you import a save file from your second play in ME2, only your actions from that playthrough will be reflected in the game.

Comment: Does this mean after starting it, you have to beat playthrough 2 before being able to import?

Comment: @DavidStarkey Only if you overwrite the endgame save, I think.

Comment: @DavidStarkey I'm pretty sure you'll need two full playthroughs to reach level 60 (I only managed level 59), but if you import an uncompleted storyline, I am fairly certain you will be prompted with the main choices to make that you haven't had time to. As for smaller things, I *think* they would mostly automatically be considered incomplete, so in the UNC: Hostage situation, the hostage would probably be considered dead.

Answer (score 2):

**ME2 will be influenced by the last ME1 playthrough you do.**
As this is the latest data!